# Pandas. Замена символа в колонке

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, замена

Люди опытные, помогите разобраться.
Из яндекс метрики приходит колонка goals_id. В ней данные с лишними символами вот в таком виде:

[image: goals_id]

Я эту колонку чищу, что бы оставались одни числа:

[image: 'df['goals_id']=df['goals_id'].replace({'[':'', ']':''})']

Вроде бы задача то элементарная, НО...
Один раз меняет. Все квадратные скобки удаляются.
На следующий день использую этот же код с новым df, не меняет. Выдаёт df без изменений.

Уже голову сломал, как так может быть, что код который еще вчера работал, сегодня уже не исполняет
действия с новым датафреймом.

Кто-нибудь с таким сталкивался?

Comment: попробуйте понять, что изменилось во входных данных. Предполагаю, что чудес не бывает

Comment: Да, согласен, но пробовал да же проделать то же самое с теми же данными с которыми получалось. Вообще не понимаю в какую сторону "копать". ))

Comment: смотрите тип данных в колонке, может они не текст, а список

Comment: А данные в df всегда одинаковые приходят - object

Comment: При чём сделать замену такую, я могу
df=df.replace({'': None})

А вот проблема именно с квадратными скобками..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Чтобы заменить не всё значение целиком, а символы в текстовой колонке, надо использовать не `Series.replace`, а [Series.str.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html) . Поскольку Pandas меняет дефолтное значение с `regex=True` на `False`, лучше явно указывать значение. В вашем случае можно сделать одно из двух

```
df['goals_id'].str.replace('[', '', regex=False).replace(']', '', regex=False)

df['goals_id'].str.replace('\[|\]', '', regex=True)
```

а вот убрать все "пустые списки" можно и при помощи [Series.replace](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.Series.replace.html)

```
 df['goals_id'].replace('[]', '', regex=False)
```

Comment: Получилось! 
Большое спасибо! ))

Comment: @ВиталийТищенко Если ответ вам помог, пометьте его как принятый.

Answer (score 0):

Это можно сделать также с помощью `.str.strip()`

```
df.goals_id = df.goals_id.str.strip('[]')
```

Comment: Спасибо! ))
Так и предполагал, что всё дело в нюансах. )